# Invalid block tag: 'shift_info', expected 'empty' ili 'endfor' Django

Tags: python, django

So, I've visited a lot of questions here on SO regarding Django block tags, but I was unable to learn from them in my perticular problem.

week_table.html

```
    {% load base_extras %}
...
    {% for shift in shifts %}
        {% if shift.user %}
            {% if user in shift.user.all or shift.user.count < shift.usernum %}
                <td class="clickable" href="{% url 'termini:shift_add_remove' shift.id %}">{% if shift.name %}{{ shift.name }}<br>{% endif %}{% for usr in shift.user.all %}{% shift_info usr %}{% endfor %}</td>
                {% else %}
                    <td>{% if shift.name %}{{ shift.name }}<br>{% endif %}{% for usr in shift.user.all %}{% shift_info usr %}{% endfor %}</td>
                    {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                    <td class="clickable" href="{% url 'termini:shift_add_remove' shift.id %}">{{ shift.name|default:"" }}</td>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

The problem is I get Invalid block tag: 'shift_info', expected 'empty' ili 'endfor' error

shift_info is defined in base_extras.py

base_extras.py

```
from django import template
import re

register = template.Library()
@register.simple_tag
def user_info(user):
    name = '%s %s' % (user.first_name, user.last_name)
    if not name.strip():
        name = user.username
    return name
```

Comment: You have named it `user_info` and calling it as `shift_info` ! Please read the error message properly.

Comment: Thank you, it's a dumb mistake, but one I've been wrapping my head around for 3 hours now -.-...

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple case of typos and not looking at your own code...